# Installing awstats in apache2 with ubuntu 13.10

Tags: performance, ubuntu, apache2, measure, awstats

I'm trying to install awstats in apache2 with Ubuntu 13.10 in a virtual machine. This is the tutorial that i followed: [Awstats installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AWStats)

I use a port to access to my virtual machine like this: "myname.es:port"

Have i to add the port in these lines?

```
  SiteDomain="yourdomain.ext"
  HostAliases="localhost 127.0.0.1 yourdomain.ext"
```

I have another problem when i have to paste the next code

```
  Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"
  Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
  Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"
  ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

into /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and i reload apache2 i see the error:

```
  * Reloading web server apache2                                             * 
  * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
  Output of config test was:
  AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
  Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
  Action 'configtest' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.
```

If i comment the line "Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" in 000-default.conf the error disappears but i cannot access to awstats using:

```
http://mydomain.ext/awstats/awstats.pl
```

This is because in my folder "/var/www"  there isn't any folder called awstats that includes the file awstats.pl.

I have tried a lot of tutorials but I do not know what can I be doing wrong. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add `+` at front of `ExecCGI`. Then reload.